# Run-time error '-2147417848 (800010108)' when saving a worksheet to PDF Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I used a VBA code attached below to save an Excel worksheet as PDF. However when I run the VBA code, it always returns me Run-time error '-2147417848 (800010108)'

Please help me, I am getting desperate. Are there any recommendations to what I am experiencing?

Note: the worksheet I am trying to print only contains the word "test" in cell A1

```vb
Sub SimplePrintToPDF()

Dim saveLocation As String
saveLocation = "C:\Users\Santo\Downloads\test123.pdf"

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=saveLocation, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
  IncludeDocProperties:=False, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

End Sub
```

I am 100% sure that my VBA code is correct since I have tested this code on another device at it runs perfectly. I have looked through sources and there are recommendations such as turn on windows feature, restart the system and so on but none worked.

Comment: What is the exact error message and which line throws it?

Comment: It says

Run-time error '-2147417848 (800010108)'
Automation error  The object invoked has disconnected from its clients.

The line that throws it is this one
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=saveLocation, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
  IncludeDocProperties:=False, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

Answer (score 1):

### Export to PDF with Error Handling

- Your code looks 'fine'. All the 'tiny' issues result in different errors. Maybe the following will help you to figure out what's going on. If you do, please share.

```vb
Sub SimplePrintToPDF()

    ' Define constants.
    Const dSubfolderName As String = "Downloads"
    Const dFileName As String = "Test123.pdf"

    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    ' Build the folder path.
    Dim pSep As String: pSep = Application.PathSeparator
    Dim dFolderPath As String
    dFolderPath = Environ("USERPROFILE") & pSep & dSubfolderName & pSep
    If Len(Dir(dFolderPath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "The path '" & dFolderPath & "' was not found.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Build the file path.
    Dim dFilePath As String: dFilePath = dFolderPath & dFileName
    
    ' Check these results in the Immediate window (Ctrl+G).
    Debug.Print "FilePath: " & dFolderPath
    Debug.Print "FileName: " & dFileName
    Debug.Print "FilePath: " & dFilePath
    
    ' Reference the sheet (charts are allowed).
    If ActiveSheet Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No visible workbooks open.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim sh As Object: Set sh = ActiveSheet

    ' Export to PDF.
    sh.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=dFilePath, _
        Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=False, _
        IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
    
    ' Explore subfolder.
    'sh.Parent.FollowHyperlink dFolderPath

ProcExit:
    On Error Resume Next
        ' any final code to run after an error
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    MsgBox "Run-time Error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub
```

Comment: It still shows the same error message Run-time error '-2147417848 (800010108)': Automation error
The object invoked has disconnected from its clients